# LMDB: How to interpret output from mdb_stat and mdb_dump utilities

Tags: caffe, lmdb

I have a functional LMDB that, for test purposes, currently contains only 21 key / value records.  I've successfully tested inserting and reading records, and I'm comfortable with the database working as intended.

However, when I use the `mdb_stat` and `mdb_dump` utilities, I see the following output, respectively:

```
Status of Main DB
   Tree depth: 1
   Branch pages: 0
   Leaf pages: 1
   Overflow pages: 0
   Entries: 1

VERSION=3
format=bytevalue
type=btree
mapsize=1073741824
maxreaders=126
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
4d65737361676573
```

`000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000d81e0000000000001500000000000000ba1d000000000000`

```
DATA=END
```

In particular, why would `mdb_stat` indicate only one entry when I have 21?  Moreover, each entry comprises 1024 x 300 values of five bytes per value.  `mdb_dump` obviously doesn't show anywhere near the 1,536,000 bytes I'd expect to see, yet the values I `mdb_put()` and `mdb_get()` on the fly are correct.  Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: is it possible you need to flush the db to disk before calling `mdb_stat`?

Comment: @Shai - Yes, a flush was done when the routine putting (and committing) records finished running and closed.  Afterwards, I ran a separate routine that randomly retrieved records and checked them for accuracy.  Everything checked out.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between an operating system's directory and an LMDB environment's data.mdb and lock.mdb files is one-to-one.

If the LMDB environment (in the OS directory) has more than one database, then the environment also contains a separate LMDB database containing all of its *named* databases.

The `mdb_stat` and `mdb_dump` utilities appear to contain minimal logic, so when they are fed a given directory via the command line, they appear to produce results only for the database storing database names and not the database(s) storing the actual data of interest.

Answer (score 2):

`4d65737361676573` is the Ascii for "Messages", which is the name of table ("sub-db" in lmdb terminology) storing the actual data in your case.

The `mdb_dump` command only dumps the main db by default. You can use the -s option to dump that sub-db, i.e.

```
mdb_dump -s Messages
```

or you can use the -a option to dump all the sub-dbs.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a sub-database, the number of entries in the main database corresponds to the number of sub-databases you've created (ie just 1).

Try using `mdb_stat -a`. This will show you a break-down of all the sub-databases (as well as the main DB). In this breakdown it will list the number of entries for each sub-database. Here you should see your 21 entries.